# Issue while using Validation through IValidateObject

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using validate method to validate my view model object. After validation if model state in invalid, my controller renders the view and show the validation summary on the view.

Problem is that on my same view there is a close button which on click performs history.go(-1). But after getting validation summary I need to press that button twice to close the view.

First hit to the button close the validation summary and another hit close that view.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but it sound like the client side scripts are not included on the view.  So as you said, the server has rendered another page and added another entry into the history stack. It's possible that adding the scripts

jquery.validate.js and
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Will prevent the first submit if there is an error and the extra entry on the history stack.